# seriousnesscongenitalanomaly in openFDA Adverse Events

Tags: api, openfda

I'm dipping my toes into the openFDA dataset and want to do some searches related to congenital anomalies. I know this data is searchable because the folks at [Social Health Insights](http://www.researchae.com/) have built a wonderful tool utilizing this as a search parameter.

I've done some reading about the fields in the [FAERS structure](http://www.fda.gov/downloads/Drugs/GuidanceComplianceRegulatoryInformation/Surveillance/AdverseDrugEffects/UCM350390.pdf) and the following queries work:

1. `?search=_exists_:seriousnessdeath&limit=5`
2. `?search=_exists_:seriousnesslifethreatening&limit=5`
3. `?search=_exists_:seriousnesshospitalization&limit=5`
4. `?search=_exists_:seriousnessdisabling&limit=5`
5. `?search=_exists_:seriousnessother&limit=5`

But the same query doesn't work for seriousnesscongenitalanomaly

`?search=_exists_:seriousnesscongenitalanomaly&limit=5`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the complement on our [ResearchAE.com](http://ResearchAE.com) project. Glad you found it useful and as an example of what people can do with the openFDA data.

To answer your question, I believe the query you mean to be doing is this:

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=_exists_:seriousnesscongenitalanomali&limit=5
```

Clickable link for that openFDA query: [https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=*exists*:seriousnesscongenitalanomali&limit=5](https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=_exists_:seriousnesscongenitalanomali&limit=5)

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks, Mark. Keep up the good work at ResearchAE.

Comment: Ryan - No problem! BTW - I noticed from your profile that you're in Indy too. Consider tweeting out to @geek_nurse who is in Indy too and built most of http://researchae.com. Have fun!

Comment: Will do, for sure!